# Программа работает медленне, чем должна

Tags: c++, opengl, qtcreator, sfml, qmake

Есть код простой небольшой демки на C++. В ней реализовывается механика "ходить, ставить блоки, убирать блоки". Захотелось разобраться, как она работает.

Есть проблема: я собираю проект - работает всё очень медленно, дёргается. Я беру уже скомпилированную версию того же самого кода- всё гладко. Но код ведь один и тот же!

Я предположил, что это связано с тем, что я компилирую для дебага и это замедляет работу программы. Перекомпилировал для релиза - ничего не изменилось.

Это меня совсем сбило с толку. Никак не могу понять, в чём причина такого странного поведения.

Ниже скину код. Но думаю, он тут не при чём. Потому что, повторюсь, скомпилированный уже до меня этот же код работает намного лучше. Правок практически ноль. Значит, дело в том, как я это собираю.

[Архив с собранным проектом.](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1UpgmZQNSc2IJ2qcGakv7IvYy6zWfhWES) Там есть и сам проект для Visual Studio, и скомпилированный exe. Который вы, однако, из соображений безопасности всё же не запускайте либо запускайте в песочнице.

```
.pro уже моего проекта - https://pastebin.com/2aACfZWU
main.cpp - https://pastebin.com/XdMPbZ0r
helpfile.hpp - https://pastebin.com/1MbEyi3R 
Версия SFML - 2.4.0
Компилятор - MinGW Builds 6.1.0 (32-bit) - какой указан на странице SFML 2.4.0
```

Comment: А проект для VisualStudio включает ключи компиляции?? Может там оптимизация какая включена. Ищите ключи компиляции

Comment: @vegorov Да я vcxproj открыл блокнотом, покопал его, ничего необычного не нашёл. Конечно, там стоит -O3, но это не особо помогает.

Comment: Если вы собираете MinGW, а уже собранное собирается с помощью VisualStudio - то возможно проблема именно в этом.  Или вы и в VisualStudio собирать пытались ? Я, к сожалению, никогда не пользовался VisualStudio, и помочь вряд-ли смогу.

Comment: @vegorov В Visual Studio я собирать конечно ещё не пробовал, в виду отстствия таковой на компьютере.. Конечно можно visual c++ компилятор засунуть и в qt creator завтра, но у меня такое ощущение, что это не должно оказывать такого большого влияния на скорость работы..

Comment: @witaway  `но у меня такое ощущение, что это не должно оказывать такого большого влияния на скорость работы.` я наоборот склоняюсь в проблемме связаной с редакторами. многопоточность через `#pragma omp` ??? qt creator  `#pragma omp` не видит .

Comment: @timob256 Заглянул в проект ещё раз. Никакх `#pragma omp` нет. Нету вообще ничего, что должно/может обеспечивать многопоточность. Такое ощущение складывается, что exe был собран вообще по другому коду, с уже добавленной многопоточностью.

Comment: Возможно, собранный вами exe использует программную эмуляцию OpenGL.  Откуда взяли библиотеку opengl32 при линковке?

Comment: @Chorkov сам как-то подхватился. Но я думаю, библиотека слинкована отсюда: `mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib`. Mingw я скачал и использовал для сборки ровно тот, который был указан [на странице SFML 2.4.0](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.0/). Там сказано: `The compiler versions have to match 100%! Here are links to the specific MinGW compiler versions used to build the provided packages:`.